# Unexpected status code 403 when trying to fetch public keys from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase PHP SDK for authenticating the user.

```
try {
    $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idToken);
} catch (FailedToVerifyToken $e) {
    printf('The token is invalid:%s',$e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf('Exception :%s',$e->getMessage());
}
```

The code is getting into exception and get the following message.

```
The token is invalid:The inner handler of Kreait\Firebase\JWT\Action\FetchGooglePublicKeys\WithPsr6Cache (Kreait\Firebase\JWT\Action\FetchGooglePublicKeys\WithGuzzle) failed in fetching keys: Unexpected status code 403 when trying to fetch public keys from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciate.

In some of the posts I have read that I need to remove FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, which I have done using

```
putenv('FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=');
```

Still no luck.